# Dynamic serving on Firebase Hosting (Vary HTTP Header)

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I would like to serve two different versions of my statically generated website: **mobile** version and **tablet, desktop** version on the **same** url - basically I want to use **Dynamic serving** and **Vary HTTP Header** - **Vary: User-Agent** as described here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/dynamic-serving

I want to use:

- **responsive web design** / **rwd** for desktop and tablet versions with desktop optimised image sizes and assets
- **adaptive web design** / **awd** with **responsive web design (rwd is much simpler implementation than desktop one - just may be some different styling for phablets)** for mobile version with mobile optimised image sizes and assets

(I should serve two different layouts and at least two different sizes for the images - mobile and desktop/tablet)

I was reading "Customize Hosting Behavior" section in Firebase Hosting documentation - https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites , but it seems there is no way to configure that at the moment.

The only way currently as suggested by Daniel Herr comment - [Dynamic serving on Firebase Hosting (Vary HTTP Header)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345217/dynamic-serving-on-firebase-hosting-vary-http-header#comment75702252_44345217)
is to use **cloud functions**:

So, I can use

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobile-detect
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/device
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/wurfl / http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/

to detect the type of device and then dynamically generate/read the mobile or desktop version of the pages.

This way we will serve the content dynamically which disables the benefits and speed of CDN, but we can still cache the pages by setting **res.set('Vary', 'User-Agent');** which may be workaround this problem.

I was wondering about more "native"/"out-of-the-box" solution, which is provided by firebase-hosting itself, like in "Rewrites" (https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites#section-rewrites):

```
"hosting": {
  // Add the "rewrites" section within "hosting"
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "**",
      "device": "MOBILE",
      "destination": "mobile/index.html"
    },
    {
      "source": "**",
      "device": "DESKTOP",
      "destination": "desktop/index.html"
    },
    {
      "source": "**",
      "device": "TV",
      "destination": "tv/index.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

This way, even if I have **TV** version of the website with tones of images and very wide layout it will not be served on **MOBILE** devices - adaptive web design.

So, currently there is no way to do that, except using custom **cloud functions** and actually generating the website dynamically.

Could you please confirm that or provide any information if this will be implemented by the **Firebase team** at some point?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want different versions of the site? What about desktop users who shrink the window? But if you really want, you probably need https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions

Comment: Thanks, Daniel Herr! So, I can use use cloud function with rewrites, source set to "**" and then this function will use https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobile-detect or https://www.npmjs.com/package/device or wurfl to determine the device type, then I can read the requested file from two different locations "/desktop" and "/mobile" ? The problem with this is: I will use cloud function to read the requested file from corresponding folders which will delay the initial request time (we need function to start) - no CDN. Probably, I can cache the response using res.set('Vary', 'User-Agent')- not sure

Comment: I have updated my question with details about cloud functions and rewrites and why I want to use adaptive + responsive designs. Basically, I don't want to serve "TV" version of the website to mobile users, the desktop and tv versions will still use responsive web design, only mobile versions will be optimised with adaptive web design and use a little bit rwd as well. Thanks!

Comment: Is your example in Rewrites working? The "device"

Comment: No, as I said the "device" is an example what I want to see implemented in firebase. It is not valid configuration, but proposal