# Firebase hosting: Serve different pages depending on device platform (mobile/pc)

Tags: javascript, firebase-hosting

I made an app using firebase hosting. I have two kinds of users ones from PC and mobile. I want to serve them different pages depending on the platform they have come from. Is there any way to do this on firebase hosting?

Comment: same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44345217/dynamic-serving-on-firebase-hosting-vary-http-header